# Validating Entity POJO object

Tags: maven, spring-mvc

I use annotated style Spring MVC. In my configuration class i declare

```
@Bean("messageSource")
public MessageSource getMessageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages");
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return messageSource;
}
```

there's 'src/main/resources' folder with messages.properties.
The validatation I want to perform for now is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "contract")
public class Contracts {
        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "payment_amount")
        private Integer paymentAmount;
}
```

and text in property file :

```
NotNull.contracts.paymentAmount = Invalid.
NotEmpty.contracts.paymentAmount = Invalid.
NotBlank.contracts.paymentAmount = Invalid.
NotNull.contracts.paymentamount = Invalid.
NotEmpty.contracts.paymentamount = Invalid.
NotBlank.contracts.paymentamount = Invalid.
```

but it doesn't work at all. The biggest problem is my other application is working fine with the same (more or less) settings.
Because it may be namespace problem I won't add pom.xml but it is possible that maven causes problems because that's the only suspect I have for now.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got the wrong error message: 
you don't specify a key in your @NotNull annotation.
Specify one or use javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message as key in your property file.

If the validation is not run at all: did you put the @Valid on the parameter of the method?

If something else, please specify what is not working.

Comment: I did put ModelAttribute Valid ClassName and BindingResults in that order. When I specify NotNull(message) it works but external file seems to be missed by spring configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I have got it working. Kind of when doing test on messages to see if they are seen by Spring i manage to get those:
in my test file:

```
String message = messageSource.getMessage("NotNull.contracts.startDate", null, Locale.getDefault());
        System.out.println(message);
```

I got the message correctly. But when I try to run my web app the only messages I see are thouse hardcoded into the Class annotation @NotNull(message=""). BTW for test to work I changed messageSource to **ResourceBundleMessageSource**